# Aggregation using $group pipeline with conditions

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

This is my data with 6 records...

```
      {
        _id: 1,
        entityProfiles:['company', 'provider']
      },
      {
        _id: 2,
        entityProfiles:['company']
      },
      {
        _id: 3,
        entityProfiles:['provider']
      },
      {
        _id: 4,
        entityProfiles:[]
      },
      {
        _id: 5,
        entityProfiles:null
      },
      {
        _id: 6,
      },
```

I need to know the total count, how many entityProfiles has 'provider' and how many has not using the $group and/or $project pipeline. 
I expected this...

```
  {
    _id: 'all',
    count: 6
  },
  {
    _id: 'providers',
    count: 2
  },
  {
    _id: 'nonProviders',
    count: 4
  },
```

... or this...

```
  {
    _id: null,
    all: 6,
    providers: 2,
    nonProviders: 4
  },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      all: {
        $sum: 1
      },
      providers: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [
            {
              $in: [
                "provider",
                {
                  $ifNull: [ "$entityProfiles", [] ]
                }
              ]
            },
            1,
            0
          ]
        }
      },
      nonProviders: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [
            {
              $in: [
                "provider",
                {
                  $ifNull: [ "$entityProfiles", [] ]
                }
              ]
            },
            0,
            1
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UGMUs_BRrAQ) | [3 documents `_id:count` pair](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VaQEA55XLI1)

Comment: works exactly as I expected, thanks so much @Valijon!

Answer (score 0):

please fix the `$addFields` aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      entityProfiles: [
        {
          $unwind: {
            path: "$entityProfiles"
          }
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$entityProfiles",
            count: {
              $sum: 1
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      all: [
        {
          $group: {
            _id: null,
            count: {
              $sum: 1
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      all: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          "$all",
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      all: {
        _id: "all",
        count: "$all.count",

      }
    }
  }
])
```